# How to replace JS function with saving "variable connections"?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a Chrome extension and I have to inject my code to original site code.

Example (**site code**):

```
let a = (() => {
    let someSecretKey = Math.random(); // <--- I need that value
    return {
        init: () => {
            const someVal = 111;
            return someVal + someSecretKey;
        }
    }
})();

// correct
console.log(a.init());
```

I have access to global `a` variable, but (my extension code):

```
a.init = () => {
    const someNewVal = 99999999;
    return someNewVal + someSecretKey;
};

// error: Uncaught ReferenceError: someSecretKey is not defined
console.log(a.init());
```

How to dynamically replace function code with saving all connections and scopes? Any `apply/call` analogue for it?

p.s. For this code, in theory, I can parse `a.init.toString()` for gets key, but in my case it's impossible because it isn't static.

p.p.s. I don't have access to modify "**site code**". I can only run my 
js code after "**site code**".

Comment: Show the real site code.

Comment: @melpomene this is impossible (NDA), but this example is 100% repeats problem

Comment: Dynamic scope is not possible in JavaScript. JavaScript Supports static scope.